# Heroku Rails Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am trying to push an app to heroku and get the standard application error page.  Note I am developing on a windows system.. :\

Here is the log retrievd using: heroku logs --tail.
I can't read this stuff.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 > 2014-09-24T14:36:07.562750+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562736+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562722+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_loa
d!'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562766+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562753+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562755+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562763+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562747+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562739+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562740+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module
:Finisher>'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562780+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562769+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562773+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562777+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562744+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2014-09-24T14:36:07.562818+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562784+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562821+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in serv
er'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562813+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562809+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562827+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'

2014-09-24T14:36:07.562836+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562822+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562826+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562834+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-09-24T14:36:07.562801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-09-24T14:36:08.276950+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-24T14:36:08.288306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-24T14:36:08.288873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-09-24T14:36:11.984377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 35747 -e production`
2014-09-24T14:36:16.359388+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:35747
2014-09-24T14:36:16.359367+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-09-24T14:36:16.359394+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-09-24T14:36:16.359392+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on a
ll interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-09-24T14:36:16.359395+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-09-24T14:36:16.359390+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360240+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/
activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': /app/ap
p/controllers/player_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, exp
ecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360245+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in
require'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360250+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360249+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_depe
ndency'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360254+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_o
r_load'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360260+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_d
ependency'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360263+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_loa
d!'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360265+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360256+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on
'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360268+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360271+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360273+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360276+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360280+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360283+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module
:Finisher>'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360285+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360288+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360298+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360301+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360307+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360294+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360319+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360297+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360322+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360303+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360315+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360323+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360328+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360334+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360329+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360332+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360326+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360335+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360343+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2014-09-24T14:36:16.360338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360348+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360340+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360344+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360358+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in serv
er'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360361+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360350+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360370+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'

2014-09-24T14:36:16.360373+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-09-24T14:36:16.360374+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-09-24T14:36:17.151592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-24T14:36:17.175066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-24T14:36:18.140439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-gorge-8204.herokuapp.com request_id=7b4b8
158-d75a-48eb-9575-cd03c746c281 fwd="174.66.192.233" dyno= connect= service= sta
tus=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log says that there is syntax error - missing `end` keyword - in one of your files:

> 2014-09-24T14:36:16.360240+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': **/app/app/controllers/player_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)**